# Microsoft Graph minimum fields

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have 2 questions regarding getting data from MS graph on behalf of a user:

1. what are the minimum fields user can get from MS Graph on another user in the same tenant and in another tenant (UPN, SID, Name, etc...). For example, in case I perform an API call on behalf of user X with basic AAD permissions in order to get data about user Y, which data the user will get?
2. Does the ID field is unique cross tenants?

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot retrieve data from another tenant. You are siloed to the tenant you authenticated to. As for the properties returned, it depends on the scopes you've requested. The [`User.ReadBasic.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions) documentation states:

   > Allows the app to read a basic set of profile properties of other users in your organization on behalf of the signed-in user. This includes display name, first and last name, email address, open extensions and photo. Also allows the app to read the full profile of the signed-in user.
2. The `id` property is a GUID, so but definition it is a globally unique identifier.